# Run spring boot website without adding HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am working with spring boot microservice application and gateway generated using jhipster. I have hosted my site on AWS EC2 instance.

Site Url: http://192.167.1.17:8082

I have redirected the port to 443 to run on https.

Let's say my site is :

http://192.167.1.17 OR http://mytestsite.com

Now the requirement is that if I type in the browser - 192.167.1.17 OR mytestsite.com

It should automatically redirect to :

http://192.167.1.17 OR http://mytestsite.com

Spring boot application has embedded tomcat. How can I do this HTTP or HTTPS redirect automatically with the hosted site on AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: Is'nt such features handled by browsers ?

Comment: I have my own website built on spring boot and https (but without jhipster), but I don't remember configuring such things. I thing by default, port 80 is http and port 443 is https, so the browser do the thing by imself.

Comment: What does your gateway do? When I do micro services on AWS, I always use their Elastic Container Service (Docker) and then put an Application Load Balancer in front. The Spring Boot application starts on a random port (http/https), which is automatically registered with the ALB. You can have also have the default std-out logging forwarded directly to Cloud Watch.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek gateway is the front end of my application. It contains all html js.

Comment: @OresteViron no is'nt such thing handled by browser.

Comment: @NeelamSharma when you type a hostname or IP address into the browser without a scheme or port, that always means port 80.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that I know, but I want the default to redirect on http or https without writing manually.

Comment: I don't understand what this means.  Put your HTTP service on port 80.  There isn't another option.

Comment: Maybe you could do this on your DNS.

Comment: It actually **is** being handled by your browser like @OresteViron mentioned. At least Chrome does that for you. You cannot change that on the server though.